# StackView Height Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uistackview

Here is what I am trying to do:

[image: Screen Shot of what I am trying to do]

The screenshot is taken from an earlier version of `iOS` device.

[image: Screen Shot of my Device]

I am using `UIStackView` I am really confused how to automatically show the first line. This is my `UIStackView` Properties in **Main.StoryBoard**.

[image: StackView Properties]

**Stack View Constraints:**

[image: StackView Constraints]

How to Show only two line on `UIStackView` and as well as how to change the height of the lines in the show in the first image.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: an easy solution willl be to add simple UIView with 1px width and gray background where you need it.

Comment: Place the vertical line UILabels along with other text UILabels with some vertical space in top and bottom.

Comment: your stackView should contain only 3 labels  with stackView.distribution = .fillEqually. Then, with autolayout, you clip 2 vertical insets views of 1 px width to the rightAnchor of the 2 first labels from the left. With autolayout, you can adjust the padding of the vertical inset views so that their height is less than your labels' heights

Answer (score 0):

Copy the source code to `Main.storyboard`.

[image]

**Storyboard source code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14460.31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14460.20"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="ViewController" useStoryboardIdentifierAsRestorationIdentifier="YES" id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="WebViewDemo" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="equalCentering" alignment="center" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="01T-u6-sKf">
                                <rect key="frame" x="16" y="20" width="344" height="80"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="fillEqually" alignment="center" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="tE3-oQ-8LA">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="114" height="80"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="15K" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="p33-9y-oh7">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="41.5" y="0.0" width="31" height="36"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Followers" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="yuq-uy-Eao">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="21" y="44" width="72.5" height="36"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="VUJ-3f-pVe">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="114" y="16" width="1" height="48"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="1" id="9Km-KS-Zha"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="fillEqually" alignment="center" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="utx-f8-Egz">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="115" y="0.0" width="114" height="80"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="5K" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="9Sx-mY-4VA">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="45.5" y="0.0" width="23" height="36"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Following" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="50u-5R-t7d">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="21" y="44" width="72.5" height="36"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="o9A-oG-RGD">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="229" y="16" width="1" height="48"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.66666666669999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="1" id="eZ8-kX-Faf"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="fillEqually" alignment="center" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="hxS-Lp-BjF">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="230" y="0.0" width="114" height="80"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="525" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wSr-MP-om2">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="41" y="0.0" width="32.5" height="36"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Burns" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xJ4-kn-IRm">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="34.5" y="44" width="45" height="36"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="VUJ-3f-pVe" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="tE3-oQ-8LA" secondAttribute="trailing" id="0dJ-QC-0DN"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="o9A-oG-RGD" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="01T-u6-sKf" secondAttribute="top" constant="16" id="0eJ-ZF-PoX"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="tE3-oQ-8LA" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="01T-u6-sKf" secondAttribute="leading" id="4XF-Ad-BxL"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="VUJ-3f-pVe" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="16" id="Cb6-ku-gaI"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="80" id="GeZ-22-Qc4"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="o9A-oG-RGD" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="utx-f8-Egz" secondAttribute="trailing" id="OqV-dm-Emb"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="utx-f8-Egz" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="VUJ-3f-pVe" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Tpj-O7-XI4"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="tE3-oQ-8LA" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="01T-u6-sKf" secondAttribute="top" id="VA4-Ir-THO"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="tE3-oQ-8LA" secondAttribute="bottom" id="Wi3-mb-45i"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="hxS-Lp-BjF" secondAttribute="trailing" id="aMM-CS-yXY"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="utx-f8-Egz" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="01T-u6-sKf" secondAttribute="top" id="bXD-RW-EuA"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="utx-f8-Egz" secondAttribute="bottom" id="bvK-yl-vkB"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="hxS-Lp-BjF" secondAttribute="bottom" id="iMQ-sM-sIg"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="hxS-Lp-BjF" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="o9A-oG-RGD" secondAttribute="trailing" id="pY7-nS-6KF"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="hxS-Lp-BjF" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="01T-u6-sKf" secondAttribute="top" id="rgj-uE-EWc"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="VUJ-3f-pVe" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="01T-u6-sKf" secondAttribute="top" constant="16" id="vLJ-85-Xhj"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="o9A-oG-RGD" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="16" id="wbg-fS-F8A"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="01T-u6-sKf" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" id="adL-or-9pL"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="01T-u6-sKf" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="15" id="bCu-2x-su3"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="01T-u6-sKf" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="zpl-R5-rv3"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    </view>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="9BY-rh-0CG">
                        <leftBarButtonItems>
                            <barButtonItem systemItem="done" id="7Ff-GP-OPr"/>
                            <barButtonItem systemItem="done" id="LFG-6n-5oQ"/>
                        </leftBarButtonItems>
                        <rightBarButtonItems>
                            <barButtonItem systemItem="done" id="SQo-Ld-g7A"/>
                            <barButtonItem systemItem="done" id="QZU-TY-dGK"/>
                            <barButtonItem systemItem="done" id="9Xe-Uw-Gzb"/>
                        </rightBarButtonItems>
                    </navigationItem>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="927.20000000000005" y="44.527736131934034"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

**Edit:**

https://bitbucket.org/Sateesh_Y/stackviewdemo/src/master/

Comment: All good but height of label Constant didn't worked they show as well as same in first image.

Comment: Height of the label is dynamic. Its always depends on the height of UIStackView. I gave 16 top space, 16 bottom space for UILabels from UIStackView, please have a look once.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check the project in Edit.

Comment: @Sateesh - providing source is fine, but your answer should also ***explain*** what you're doing to solve the question.